# how to implement permissions on routes and functions in sails.js?

Tags: node.js, permissions, sails.js, sails-postgresql, sails-permissions

I'm new in sails and I have a PostgreSQL database. I want to implement a user management. I have some users, `each user can be assigned to multiple groups`, `each group can be assigned to multiple roles` and `each role can have some permissions`! I checked document of sails permissions but I didn't get it well. for example, I want some groups not to be able to add or edit users or I want some roles not to be able to see user management menu. what should I do?

Comment: I would do it in a low level. Make it clear and simple. 
You could construct some complexity inside config/policies, but i would just keep this logic inside controllers. When user opens a page, it hits controller. And controller gets the permission of that user and decides, or the user has permission to view something or not.

Answer (score 1):

I may be a little late to post answer here, But there is a way available for access control in sails.

Sails has built-in policy based access control system.

1. Policy

Policies in Sails are designed for controlling binary ("yes or no") access to particular actions. They work great for checking whether a user is logged in or for other simple "yes or no" checks, like whether the logged in user is a "super admin".

But for Dynamic permissions,

2. Helpers

Link for documentation of helper, [access-control-and-permissions](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies/access-control-and-permissions)

For more complex permission schemes, like those in which a requesting user agent's access rights depend on both who they are and what they're trying to do, you'll want to involve the database. While you can use policies to accomplish this, it's usually more straightforward and maintainable to use a helper.

One can find example here,
[Using helper for access control and permission](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies/access-control-and-permissions#?dynamic-permissions)

So you can use postgreSQL for storing roles and their respective permissions and retrive user role and check permission on need in policy/helper.

Answer (score 0):

Sails.js has no ACL managment
You have to use 3rd party middleware like [roles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/roles) or [role-acl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/role-acl)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like what's most important is the association of the user to the permission (or role). So you could consider making models for each tier (user, role, group) or you can make a model for each kind of group and/or role (though that sounds like it could get out of hand) and then have the models associated with eachother. Then in the view action you can set what the permissions are (aka what groups or roles are allowed to see that page). Also in the markup you can set who is allowed to even see a button. 
For example: 
`isSales` could be a boolean on your group or roles model for a user that is in sales and they are allowed to see the edit button to change the price of something. So in your markup you have:

```
 <div v-if="user.isSales">
  <button> Edit price </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nothing in fariba's description mention that he's using Vue.js.

Comment: Why not? It comes pre-packaged with sails and would help deal with fariba's front end ui issues.